# Replaceing _custom_background_cb

Tags: theme-development, custom-background, add-theme-support

I'm making a theme where I'm adding support for the custom background feature with this standar function:

```
// fig. 1

<?php

function custom_theme_support() {
        add_theme_support('custom-background', array(
                'default-color'    => '333333',
                'wp_head_callback' => '_custom_background_cb'
        ));
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'custom_theme_support');

?>
```

However I was usatisfied with the way the default function `_custom_background_cb` handles the settings, because it only gives the option to center the background image horizontaly. So i made this function in my `functions.php` file:

```
// fig. 2

<?php

function themeslug_custom_background() {

        $background = set_url_scheme(get_background_image());
        $color = get_background_color();

        if ($color === get_theme_support('custom-background', 'default-color')) { 
                $color = false;
        }

        if (!$background&&!$color) { 
                return;
        }

        $style = $color ? "background-color: #$color;" : false;

        if ($background) { 
                $style = "background: #$color url('$background') no-repeat fixed; background-size: cover; background-position: center;";
        }
?>
        <style type="text/css" id="custom-background-css">
                body.custom-background { 
                        <?php echo trim($style); ?>
                }
        </style>
<?
        }
?>
```

And changed the `wp_head_callback` seen in fig. 1 to:

```
// fig. 3

function custom_theme_support() {
        add_theme_support('custom-background', array(
                'default-color'    => '333333',
                'wp_head_callback' => 'themeslug_custom_background'
        ));
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'custom_theme_support');
```

However, the `_custom_background_cb` function is still called, instead of the `themeslug_custom_background` I created.

I am aware this function will void some of the background settings in the wp-admin/customize window, but this is for a very minemalistic theme, and its more important for me to center the background, than it is to be able to chage this setting in the wp-admin.

Comment: @ialocin I'm new here, so I'm not that familliar with the guidelines for questions, but I did not find anythig that said i could not thank people in advance for any help they might provide, I also do not understand why you removed the functions and php tags from my post, as this is the main content, could you please explain this reasoning to me? :)

Comment: Your approach is pretty much the text book one, so in my mind it should work. Do you have debugging enabled and excluded the possibility that there is another problem with your code?

Comment: It is not a big problem, but it is generally considered unnecessary noise, so I removed it along with the two superfluous tags.

Comment: I get no errors or other issues, it simply uses the default function instead, thats why I'm at a loss as to how to aproach this problem

Comment: when reading the sourcecode the style output is
<style type="text/css" id="custom-background-css">
body.custom-background { background-image: url('http://www.example.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/image.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: top center; background-attachment: fixed; }
</style>
so it looks as if it just ignores my function and goes with the default one.

Comment: I am stumped at the moment and got to go now.

Comment: Your code works. There is something else interfering.

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: Yes, of course! How else would I know that the code works?

Comment: Maybe you just have supernatural psychic powers :) Or for more enlightened, rational and agnostic people among us, you have a server with WordPress running inside your brain, so of course you can test the code by looking at it :) @s_ha_dum

Comment: No but its wierd, because i have tested it on several differnt hosting companies where i have domains, and on local host, and i always get the same problem

Comment: are you shure it works? the page looks fine when it does not work too, what you have to look for is how it sets up the body.custom-background class in the sourcecode

Comment: you wont get any errors either way

Comment: The main issue is that it sets background-position: top center;, i can of cource add an !important tag to the setting in style.css, but it would be nice to have wordpress actually do it right..

Comment: if you look at the function its supposed to be background-position: center center;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
wp_head_callback
```

as parameter at your arguments array, which is *wrong*.

It should be

```
wp-head-callback
```

which is the *correct* spelling.

Because of the wrong spelling the default value for `wp-head-callback` which is `_custom_background_cb` has been used, as the wrong spelling is unknown to Wordpress - of course.

Comment: When I read through the code for the old function I saw it, I was just about to post a edit x)

Comment: That is actually where it hit me too :) Please delete your answer, we don't want to promote deprecated functions - thanks! @Isak

Comment: My pleasure! @Isak